# How to make a connection with my ontology?

Tags: android, ontology

I created an ontology with Protégé. Then I created an Android interface which contains two edit texts and a button. The main function of my code is to make a connection between my application and the ontology and store these data into it. I use a triple store for storage.

But it didn't work correctly. I'm using Sesame as server but I don't know how to get the correct URL of the "update" service. I might have made other errors but here is my activity's code:

```
package com.example.ontologie1;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.DatatypeProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.Individual;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private Button buttonconnexion;
  private EditText editpseudo;
  private EditText editpassword;
  public String ps;
  public String pa;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editpseudo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.welcomeedittextlogin);
    editpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.welcomeedittextpassword);
    buttonconnexion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.welcomebuttonconnexion);
    buttonconnexion.setOnClickListener(click1);
  }

  protected OnClickListener click1 = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
      ps= editpseudo.getText().toString();
      pa= editpassword.getText().toString();
      try {
        connexion(ps , pa);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  };

  protected void connexion(String pseudo,String password) throws IOException {

    String requete = "<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .\n"
        + "INSERT DATA {\n"
        + "    <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology_profile.owl#USER>   a   onto:USER;\n"
        + "        onto:Login  " + pseudo + ";\n"
        + "        onto:Password  " + password + ";\n"
        + "}";


    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("<http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository#>");
    NameValuePair[] paramRequete = {
        new NameValuePair("query", requete),
    };
    post.setRequestBody(paramRequete);

    InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    Toast t = null ;
    t.setText(in.toString());
    t=new Toast(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with Android programming, but there are some issues that suggest you need to rethink your goals.

An ontology is not a database. You don't store data in an ontology, and you don't need an ontology to store data in a triplestore.

To store data in a triplestore (using SPARQL), your triplestore needs a SPARQL endpoint. That endpoint has a URI that you send your `POST` or `GET` request to. If you installed Sesame on your local machine, that URI may look like `http://localhost:8080/sparql`. If you want to insert data, the triplestore needs to allow that.

You also need a valid SPARQL query, which your `requete` is not. The first line,

```
<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
```

is not complete. Usually there are `PREFIX`es on the first lines of a SPARQL query, but they don't end with a `.`. For example:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
```

To use the prefix `onto:` as you do, you need to define it in the same way. For a complete SPARQL tutorial, see [this](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example).

Also, the lines

```
Toast t = null ;
t.setText(in.toString());
t=new Toast(null);
```

will generate a `NullPointerException`, as you call a method on `t` that is `null`.